# vue upload image from asset dir

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to upload image from asset dir to uploadcare. I am loading the image and giving post req to uploadcare.

```
this.userinfo.map(user => {
  var src = require("../assets/" + user.image);
  console.log(src, typeof src);
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("UPLOADCARE_PUB_KEY", "084e96d18b8afe25c51c");
  fd.append("UPLOADCARE_STORE", 1);
  fd.append("file", src);

  let config = {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
  };

  this.axios.post("https://upload.uploadcare.com/base/", fd, config).then(v => {
    console.log(v);
  });
});
```

but it is showing bad 400 ( bad request)

may be the problem with loading the image in src because the src type is showing string but i need to send file to uploadcare..

How can I load vue assets folder image in a variable and post as formData???
uploadcare docs
https://uploadcare.com/docs/api_reference/upload/request_based/#multipart